# Fast filtering after Get-ChildItem

Tags: regex, powershell, filter

With `PowerShell 5.1` and the new `.NET framework`, it is finally possible to work with long path names using `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\?\C:\MyPath"`.

In the code below we try to filter out files and folders that are in specific directories (as well as the directories themselves), because we're not interested in them.

This code works fine, but we were wondering if there is a better or faster way of doing this instead of building a long regex string?

In case the array `$IgnoredFolders` gets really long, it might take more time for `-notmatch` to make the decision. I'm not an expert in regex and how long they may become, so any feedback is welcome.

```
<#
# Path
    Folder A         
        File folder A.txt
    Folder B         
        File folder B.txt
    Folder C         
        File folder C.txt

    File root A.txt  
    File root B.txt  
#>

$Path = 'S:\testFolder'

$IgnoredFolders = @(
    "$Path\Folder B"
    "$Path\Folder C"
)

$RegexIgnoredFolders = $IgnoredFolders.ForEach({
    [Regex]::Escape("\\?\$_")
}) -join '|'

@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\$Path" -Recurse).Where({ 
    $_.FullName -notmatch $RegexIgnoredFolders
}) | select fullname
```

The output of this code is:

```
"$Path\Folder A"              
"$Path\File root A.txt"     
"$Path\File root B.txt"          
"$Path\Folder A\File folder A.txt"
```

Comment: Maybe by using the `-Filter` and/or the `-Exclude` parameters instead of regex in a `Where` clause?

Comment: *In case the array `$IgnoredFolders` gets really long, it might take more time for `-notmatch` to make the decision.* Did you actually *measure* that, or do you just suspect it? In case of the latter: get evidence and verify that there actually *is* a problem that needs fixing. Otherwise don't bother. Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Part of the slow down is the foreach loop. I suspect Theo is right. If you could replace the loop with just one single command and exclude what you don't want it'll be faster. But they aren't demanding commands. So I suspect very little improvement. Maybe a few seconds.-exclide handles an array list. So you could just put `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\$Path" -Recurse -exclude $ignoredfolders`

Comment: @RobertCotterman thx for the tip, but `-Exclude` only works on the leaf of a path, not on the `FullName` property. @AnsgarWiechers thx for the tip, it's just a question, not something I've measured. So for now, I'll leave it as is as it works fine.

Comment: If you run the get-childitem In there and do a basename you could get just the leaf. Or better yet just change your ignoredfolders to just the leaf name instead of $path\leaf name

Comment: The problem with that is if multiple folders have the same `BaseName`.